# Double Quoted Strings in C++

Tags: c++

How to converted string with space in double quoted string.
For Example:
I get string

```
c:\program files\abc.bat
```

I want to convert this string to "`c:\program files\abc.bat`" but only if there is space in the string.

Comment: Is it a `std::string` or `const char*`?

Comment: What do you need to happen if there is already a double quote in the string? Is this different depending on whether there is a space in the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the STL string `s` contains the string you want to check for a space:

```
if (s.find(' ') != std::string::npos)
{
  s = '"' + s + '"';
}
```

Comment: Would it be more efficient to use `'"'` instead of `"\""`?

Answer (score 2):

Search for white spaces. If found add \" to the front and the end of the string. That would be an escaped quotation mark.

Comment: Before enclosing the string in ", search for existing " and prefix them with \.  This will handle strings with " inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str = get_your_input_somehow();

if (str.find(" ") != std::string::npos) {
  str = "\"" + str + "\"";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `str.find(' ') != std::string::npos)`?

Comment: If there's the whitespace is at the beginning, 0 is returned.

Comment: @Manuel--whoops--it was too late at night--you're absolutely right!  (editing now)